# Magento 2 How to change "Grand Total to be Charged" text in order emails

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2 how to change "Grand Total to be Charged" text in emails?

Text is found in this file vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order/Totals.php

How to override this file to my theme or module?

Thanks
Santosh

Answer (score 0):

To override this class, you need to create your own class and extend the original class.

You need to declare override class in the `di.xml` file. Follow the steps below:

> app/code/MilanDev/ExtendsCore/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MilanDev_ExtendsCore" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/MilanDev/ExtendsCore/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" type="MilanDev\ExtendsCore\Rewrite\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals"/>
</config>
```

> app/code/MilanDev/ExtendsCore/Rewrite/Magento/Sales/Block/Order/Totals.php

```
<?php
namespace MilanDev\ExtendsCore\Rewrite\Magento\Sales\Block\Order;

class Totals extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals
{

    /**
     * Initialize order totals array
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _initTotals()
    {
        // ...........

        if ($this->getOrder()->isCurrencyDifferent()) {
            $this->_totals['base_grandtotal'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'base_grandtotal',
                    'value' => $this->getOrder()->formatBasePrice($source->getBaseGrandTotal()),
                    'label' => __('Your custom text'), // changed
                    'is_formated' => true,
                ]
            );
        }

        // ........
    }
}
```